# What is the purpose of metadata in xml file?

Tags: android, metadata

I saw a program in which they use metadata. What is the purpose of this..?

```
"meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"
           android:resource="@xml/device_admin_sample" "
```

Answer (score 2):

They "need this" because the documentation tells them they "need this". In this case, they are implementing a device admin app, and [the documentation for such apps tells them that they need to create this metadata file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#manifest), specifically to list the security policies they require.

More generally, [`<meta-data>` is a way to add more information about a component](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html), that might be used by frameworks utilizing that component.